Fix A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
how to fix the warning Fix A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Here is my code:
result = data['Triplet'].apply(lambda x: process_sub_graph(x))
result is a list of tuple
then
data['Input'] = [result.iloc[i][0] for i in range(len(result))]
data['Entity'] = [result.iloc[i][1] for i in range(len(result))]

I tried:
data.iloc[:,'Input']
but it didnt work either
Updated code:
data = pd.read_csv('data/recheck_data.csv')
data = data[['Question', 'Triplet', 'Answer']] 
data.dropna(inplace=True)

def valid_sample(item):
    # DO THINGS
    if item:
        return False
    return True 

data['valid_sample'] = data['Triplet'].apply(lambda x: valid_sample(x))
data = data[data['valid_sample'] == True] 



def process_sub_graph(sub_graph: str):
    
    # DO SOMETHING
    return _,_ 
    
    
        
result = data['Triplet'].apply(lambda x: process_sub_graph(x))
data['Input'] = [result.iloc[i][0] for i in range(len(result))]
data['Entity'] = [result.iloc[i][1] for i in range(len(result))]



What line of code do you use to create the data variable? It is likely you need a .copy() in your code somewhere

result is a Pandas Series rather than a List. Your code works for me. Please provide [MRE] giving the error.

result is a Series where each element is a tuple of two element

@EmiOB hmm that's function is quite long

I know it's a duplicated question but that's dawg link doesn't help T.T

@tjns we can't help with the information you've given, as the line that is creating the copied data isn't in your question. Are there any lines in your function to create  data  where you filter another dataframe? maybe a .loc or .iloc? I can't say 100% that would be the problem as your question doesn't contain the previous code used. Somewhere you're filtering a dataframe, saving it as a new dataframe but not using .copy(), so the new dataframe is still linked to the old hence the warning.  If you want more help than that (and the useful link provided), you need to update your question.

I would also strongly recommend reading the link from @user19077881 about a minimal reproducible example, it will help you ask better questions which are less likely to be downvoted/closed

@tjns add .copy() on to the end of your line:
data = data[data['valid_sample'] == True] so it becomes data = data[data['valid_sample'] == True].copy()
